# sed insert/append and printing pattern space

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I want to manipulate a textfile, so that blocks of indented lines will be enclosed with {{{ and }}}.

This is where I'm stuck:

```
  1 /^\ [^\ ]/,/^[^\ ]/{        # match range: all indented plus line after that
  2    b fixIndented            # branch
  3 }
  4 
  5 /^[^\ ]/{p;b}               # print all non-indented outside range and exit.
  6                             
  7 :fixIndented
  8 /^[^\ ]/{                   # match last line of range
  9    x;                       # swap Holdbuffer und patternSpace, edit patternSpace
 10    i\
 11       {{{
 12    a\
 13       }}}
 14    p;
 15    x;p;
 16 }
 17 H;                          # write each line in range into holdBuffer
```

I think line 15 should read in the hold buffer (containing what I swapped there in line 9) and then print it, *after* the manipulated pattern space (lines 10-13) has been printed (14).
But that doesn't happen. Instead, it appears to merge the line from the hold buffer into the pattern space. Like so:

```
bla
blubb
 foo1
 bla2
 foo3
sadgfasdf
bar
foo
```

becomes:

```
bla
blubb
      {{{

 foo1
 bla2
 foo3
sadgfasdf
      }}}   
bar
foo
```

I'd be very grateful if somebody took the time to point me into the right direction here. Thanks,

Comment: +1 for good question with interesting problem.  ..... But unless your "married" to sed, awk would be a much easier solution to this problem. Good luck

Comment: interesting ! Good exercise. Lets try !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with sed also but with awk it is much simple:

```
cat file
bla
blubb
 foo1
 bla2
 foo3
sadgfasdf
bar
foo

awk '!s && /^ /{s=1; $0 = " {{{" ORS $0} s && /^[^ ]/{s=0; $0 = " }}}" ORS $0}1' file
bla
blubb
 {{{
 foo1
 bla2
 foo3
 }}}
sadgfasdf
bar
foo
```

Comment: @michaelP: I told you it would be easier ; -) Good luck to all.

Comment: That solves the problem, thank you very much! I'll have to check how it blends in with the bigger context tomorrow at work (that is, see if the indented braces will be a problem), but it is an impressive one-liner, doing what I wanted!
@shellter: No, I'm not married to sed, and seeing how easy this has been solved with awk, I sure would think about filing a divorce now :)